# Android set speakerphone on programmatically

Tags: android, audio, speakerphone

I am trying to set speakerphone on in a call programmatically using `audiomanager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true)` in a service but it seems it is not working and I don't know why.
Should I do something else?

Thanks

Comment: A similar question was asked and answered [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617381/turn-on-speakerphone-whenever-an-outgoing-call-is-made/21328490#21328490

Answer (score 18, accepted):

check if your manifest file has the permissions need to do this operation.

I think this is the permission you need [MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS)

Answer (score 4):

In android 4.1 and more when you make a call the phone turn off the speaker phone automatically. So What you need to do is to add the speakerphone on in the reciever that listens for the call being made when the state is "offHook" and even put a 0.5 second delayed to turn on the speaker like that:

```
final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
    audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
    MainActivity.shouldTurnSpeakerOn = false;
    MainActivity.shouldTurnSpeakerOff = true;
    Log.d("incoming_call","speaker_on");                    
    }
}, 500);
```

Remember to add this to the Phone state listener. And to run off the speaker phone when the state is IDLE (needed for earlier versions).

Good Luck.

Comment: I don't know the reason why but this delay of 500 ms is required. Thanks!

Comment: not working in android 10 pixel 2 do you know the reason?