# how to play sound instaed Headset ,from speaker directly on android?

Tags: android, speaker

I am trying to play a media file and Listening it on Headset, Now I am trying to give a soft 
button that using for SpeakerOn and Speakeroff.

```
mAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL); 
mAudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
```

I have give permission also in Androidmanifest.xml .
But on calling these Apis, Mode is changed and using isSpeakerOn() api it showing the 
speaker status as we expected but In real time I am still getting sound from Headset
only not from Speaker?

Give me some guideline so that we can achieve this switching of sound from headSet 
to Speaker?

Comment: Your question is quite confusing: THe microphone is the device you use for recording / catching sound, it never produces sound.

Comment: sorry Nanne ..Listening on Headset>>>>and with some sofetBUTTON want to enable the speaker so that we can get sound from Speaker only.

Comment: Check the following links:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663108/android-set-speakerphone-on-programmatically

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119060/android-getting-audio-to-play-through-earpiece


thanks
Manish

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `audioManager.setWiredHeadsetOn(boolean on)` set to **`false`**.