# how to make a phone call with speaker on

Tags: android, android-intent

brought here is the code for making a phone call from my Activity

```
public void makeAPhoneCallWithSpeakerOn()
{
  String uri = "tel:" + posted_by.trim() ;
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
  intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
  startActivity(intent); 
}
```

question is:

how can I make the phone call and turn the speaker on?

10X Elad

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an [AudioManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html) to turn on the speakers and a [CallStateListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html) for receiving the end of the call.

Comment: So you're saying that i should listen to outgoing calls? If so how can I tell that they came from my application?

Comment: No, before you start the call you register the listener, then activate the speakerphones. After receiving `CALL_STATE_IDLE` you remove the listener and deactivate the speakerphones again.

Comment: Will try and report back here

Comment: I looked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663108/android-set-speakerphone-on-programmatically), 
and using the listener- I caught the off hook event and called:
  `AudioManager audioManager = 
  (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE); 
   audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);

    audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);`
also added permission MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS, not working yet.

Comment: Then I guess the `setSpeakerphoneOn` has to be called on STATE_RINGING, as it might have no effect on STATE_OFFHOOK

Comment: It works, without setMode(). turns out APK wasn't installed successfully

Comment: Hi @EladGelman , Could you expand on your answer, I have a similar question and I am not sure what to do. http://stackoverflow.com/q/12995902/804503

Answer (score -2):

I found out that if I add the code in this following order works best for me

```
      audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE); 
      audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL); 
      audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
```

whereas the following not work for me if I setSpeakerphoneOn(true) at the first line:

```
       audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
       audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
       audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
```

Comment: 2nd doesn't work because audioManager isn't defined yet