# Start call with speaker via intent

Tags: android, android-intent, call

I have a service that start a call when something happened, that works prefect but my question is how can I start it with speaker on?(and remove the speaker after 2 min?)

---

according to your all anwsers,

this code should work -

```
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + num));
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);// (i'm starting the call from service..)
                startActivity(intent); //the call start here, work perfect
                AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
                audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
```

well, It doesnt work.. why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to make a phone call with speaker on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8791754/how-to-make-a-phone-call-with-speaker-on)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
```

Use this to turn speaker on once call is picked up.

Premission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

Register `PhoneStateListener` to know when call is picked up.
urn speaker on when call state is `TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK`

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an [AudioManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html) to turn on the speakers and a [CallStateListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html) for checking if the call is over. If is not, check if it lasts two minutes.